# How to calculate a ratio in BigQuery when there is a one is to many relation?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a sample data set that looks like this:

| Transaction ID | Session |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 |
| Null | 4 |
| Null | 4 |

I am trying to get the ratio of successful sessions to all sessions.
So in this case, we have a 75 success ratio as 3 out of 4 sessions have a transaction. How do I achieve this in BigQuery?
Transaction ID is unique but Session ID can be duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to count session_id only of sessions with transactions and then divide by the total sessions:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IF(transaction_id is not null, session_id, null)/COUNT(DISTINCT session_id) as ratio
FROM sessions_table
```